# Can't change owner of cars in hyperledger fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-chaincode

I tried to create a package of cars but when I invoke transport chaincode to change the owner of the cars in the package, its owner wasn't changed.

https://github.com/JackAtlas10/Learing-Fabric/blob/master/Learn%20GoLang/Go%20L/tempContract.go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues in your code.

1. In 'InitPackage' method, you are adding empty array of cars (you should add array of car inside it)
2. In 'Transport' method, the for loop is not correct. You are executing loop on a string variable, 'cNum'. According to your code, whenever you will call 'AddCarsToPkg' method, the 'cNum' variable of the package store a new value (or will not reserves the old car numbers)

I have solution in my mind. It may be helpful for you.
That is:

- Add 'cNum' as a element of 'Car' structure & remove this element from 'Packages' struct
- before 'PutState' also set the value of Car element 'cNum'
- In 'Transport' method, replace for loop with below given code

```
    for i := range tempPkg.cars {
        carIndex := tempPkg.cars[i].cNum
        car, _ := s.QueryCar(ctx, carIndex)
        car.Owner = newOwner
        car.Status = "Handed Over"
        carAsBytes, _ := json.Marshal(*car)
        err := ctx.GetStub().PutState(carIndex, carAsBytes)
        if err != nil {
            return fmt.Errorf("Error in Puting state to data base%s", err.Error())
        }
        tempPkg.cars[i].Owner = newOwner
        tempPkg.cars[i].Status = "Handed Over"
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, that is my wrong code, my codes are as same as you except I left my initial package empty, but they still won't work, I had my status changed to "Handing Over" by running AddCarsToPkg method, but I can't change my owner
<https://docs.google.com/document/d/1qD5qtBpkaxyl_Yww9Qq7YkppGtFG0Hr81HMryV779d4/edit> 
You can see my result

Comment: It only work when I change package of Cars to one care package @@

Comment: change **Packages** struct fields as exported fields by start it with Upper case letter (example below)

type Packages struct {
 Cars   []Car `json:"cars"`
 Status string `json:"status"`
 CNum   []string `json:"cNum"`
}

Comment: Use code (in below link) 

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AlvAFR4RuXWCrjxtYjbpn24rFCVuvYiN/view?usp=sharing